# Flutter Firebase Database store/ read data by date

Tags: mongodb, firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to NoSql schema design. I would like to store some race schedule, this is how i do it now.

```
/{Year}
------>/{Month}
------>------>/{Day}
------>------>------/{raceNumber}
------>------>------>------>/{raceMeta}
```

[image]

I have the following questions:

1. Is it possible to retrieve a result like

```
["dd/mm/YYYY",...]
```

or

```
["2018":
        ["01":
              ["01":...],
              ...
        ...
        ],
 "2019":
...]
```

, without initializing all child node? I've found **shallow** query for Firebase, but seems it can only query the single layer.

2. Is this a good design/practice to structure such data in that way?

Thanks for the help!

3. I would like to have an function to navigate through records, for example selecting a date from a list of dates from the database, and by simply clicking arrows to move forward/ backward, how can I archive that?

Answer (score 0):

Change the format of date from `31/12/2022` to `31-12-2022` and you are good to go.